# Swift 2.0 Errors

Tags: xcode, build-error, swift2

I am trying to use the following code:

```
func redrawShape(shape: Shape, completion:() -> ()) {
    for (idx, block) in shape.blocks.enumerate() {
        let sprite = block.sprite!
        let moveTo = pointForColumn(block.column, row: block.row)
        let moveToAction: SKAction = SKAction.moveTo(moveTo, duration: 0.05)
        moveToAction.timingMode = .EaseOut
        sprite.runAction(moveToAction, completion: nil)
}
```

I get an error at this line:

```
sprite.runAction(moveToAction, completion: nil)
```

The error says:

> Cannot invoke 'runAction' with an argument list of type '(SKAction, completion: nil)'

I do not understand how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion handler is not an optional. You need to pass something. You can pass an empty closure:

```
sprite.runAction(moveToAction, completion: {})
```

Or, as matt points out, the better approach is to use the other form:

```
sprite.runAction(moveToAction)
```

Matt's answer is really the better one.

Comment: Actually it _is_ optional - the whole parameter is optional.

Comment: OK; it's not *an* optional (i.e. a thing you can pass `nil` to). I didn't see that they had an overload for it, though.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the wrong method. If you have no completion handler, then do not call `runAction(_:completion:)`. Call simple `runAction(_:)`, like this:

```
 sprite.runAction(moveToAction)
```

In other words, you have two options:

- You can call `runAction(_:)` if you have no completion handler, or
- you can call `runAction(_:completion:)` if you have a completion handler.

But what you *cannot* do is call `runAction(_:completion:)` if you have no completion handler - as you are trying to do.